# I do not understand this Unity editor OutOfRangeException

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, unity-editor

This is what I see in the unity console...

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
> index System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32
> index) (at <4ba27aa039714eafa1e8892e51af2932>:0)
> GameManagerOneHundred.myHandStrength () (at
> Assets/GameManagerOneHundred.cs:1146) GameManagerOneHundred.smartBot
> () (at Assets/GameManagerOneHundred.cs:1154) FunctionTimer.Update ()
> (at Assets/FunctionTimer/Scripts/FunctionTimer.cs:76)
> FunctionTimer+MonoBehaviourHook.Update () (at
> Assets/FunctionTimer/Scripts/FunctionTimer.cs:53)

Can anyone decipher this?

I don't understand what index is malfunctioning.

What the heck is `index System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]`?

Can I use `(at <4ba27aa039714eafa1e8892e51af2932>:0)` to debug somehow?

I am trying to debug and I don't understand where the bug is!

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is a call stack. It lists the sequence of steps (methods calling other methods) taken in your code to arrive at the problematic call that resulted in an `OutOfRangeException`.

Let's dissect. First the offending bit:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index)
```

This simply indicates you have a `List<T>` somewhere in your code, which you're trying to access a value from by index. But that index doesn't exist.

It mentions `get_Item` because that's the call that an Indexer like `myList[i]` boils down to: `myList.get_Item(i)`.

So the error says "Hey, that index you're using is not valid. A valid index is 0 or greater, but not greater than the index of the last element".

Helpful, but not yet great, because that doesn't tell us where we try to get that value. The next bit does though.

```
GameManagerOneHundred.myHandStrength () (at Assets/GameManagerOneHundred.cs:1146)
```

It tells you you tried to access that element in the `GameManagerOneHundred` script. And in the `myHandStrength()` method in particular. And even more detailed, you did so on line 1146 of that script.

Great, now we know where to look. In some cases that might be a method you call from different locations, taking different steps to get to that call. In that case it might be helpful to look at the rest of the stack. Once again, each bit simply tells you where a call was made, and on what exact line.

So in your case it went

`FunctionTimer.Update()` -> `GameManagerOneHundred.smartBot()` -> `GameManagerOneHundred.myHandStrength()` -> `Item access EXPLOSION`

So now it's up to you to check what's going on with that call. Perhaps your list is empty when you don't expect it to be? Or maybe you're trying to access the 3rd value when it just has 2.